Not all auxiliary files are deleted in LaTeX VSCode extension
I am using the VSCode extension for LaTeX for my work. I have several tex files and it makes it very hard to navigate the panel with all the auxiliary files laying around.
I have decided to delete the auxiliary files after compiling by using the json settings below:

Where I set the setting into onBuilt so that files are deleted whether there is success or failure.
However, I've noticed that not all auxilary files are deleted after this setting.

Above are the remaining auxiliary files. Is there any way to force tex to delete ALL files other than the extensions .tex and .pdf?
Thanks in advance!

You might want to keep the .synctex.gz file as well because that allows you to jump from the code to the corresponding position in the pdf and vice versa.

Looks like you're having trouble getting VSCode's LaTeX Workshop to clean up all those pesky auxiliary files after compilation. Yeah, the onBuilt setting in settings.json is a good start, but it doesn't always catch everything.
Those leftover files you mentioned (.aux, .bbl, .blg, .log, .out) are pretty typical LaTeX byproducts. Here are a few ways you could tackle this:

If you're using MiKTeX 2.9, try adding the --clean flag to texify in your LaTeX Workshop settings. That usually does a pretty good job at cleaning things up.
Another option is to write a quick cleanup script yourself and hook it into LaTeX Workshop. That way you have complete control over what gets deleted.
Or, if you're open to switching things up, TeX Live handles cleanup a bit better out of the box. Might be worth considering if this is a recurring headache.

Just a heads up though - if you're working on something big with lots of references and dependencies, be a bit careful with aggressive cleanup. Maybe keep a backup of your project before making any major changes to how things compile.
